# Pretty printing a parse tree to std out?

Tags: c++, printing, tree, stdout

I have written a simple recursive descent parser in C++.

I need a way to print it to std out but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have a class Node and it has a function `printSymbol()` to print its symbol.

It has a `std::list <Node*> m_children` for its children.

Given this, how can I pretty print the parse tree to std out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an overload to `printSymbol` that takes an indent-level, or a default value, either works:

```
void printSymbol(unsigned indent = 0) const
{
    std::cout << std::string(indent,' ') << m_symbol << '\n';
    for (auto child : m_children)
        child->printSymbol(indent+2);
}
```

Given any single node a direct call to `printSymbol()` should simply output the symbol, a newline, and all its children if it has any, all properly indented. Given a root pointer this should dump your entire parse hierarchy to stdout. You can get extraordinarily creative regarding ascii art, console-dependent line chars if you're really set on it, but it can get tedious quickly, I warn you.

Regardless, this should at least give you a picture you can print. Either that or I utterly misunderstood your question.

Best of luck